# Unable to add Active Directory User to Azure SQL

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I am trying to add Active Directory User into Azure Sql database with below query from Azure Function APP, Facing some of the issues.

I need to add the Active Directory User to Azure SQL from azure function app, not on-premises. 
Tried on-premises first, working fine with Keeping full AD passowrd connection string, and giving query like 
`CREATE USER [EMAIL@DOMAIN] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` 
If i host in azure app service/ azure function not working.

C# Code

```
var cn = GetADConnection(dbName);

var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

string accessToken = await tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");

string query = @"CREATE USER [B19634@uniper.energy] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER";

  var command = new SqlCommand(query, cn);

        try
        {

            cn.AccessToken = accessToken;
            cn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Info(ex.HResult + "_" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
        }
```

Tried two ways mentioned below ,

One way:

For this we require SQL Active Directory Password Authentication connection string mandate, It is working fine from on-premises .Net Applications(Console/web). If we host them in Azure app service and try with same code, will be getting the below error

**One or more errors Occured**

Second way:

We turned on Managed Service Identity to my Azure Function App, and tried to generate AD token and used it for Adding AD User. Getting following error.

**principal '[EMAIL@DOMAINNAME] ' could not be found at this time. Please try again later.**

I got this link from Google and came across some article and tried like below,

```
CREATE USER [name_emaildomain#EXT#@yourcompany.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

Still the issue is the same.

Comment: I responded to your MSDN Post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b70fd7c2-afe6-4651-8966-9ab17cc80e67/unable-to-add-active-directory-user-to-azure-sql?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: Chandrasekhar: note that [cross-posting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting) without declaration is considered anti-social on the internet. This is because your readers in two or more locations are not likely to know that other copies exist, and that other people may already have answered the question. Thus, there is a risk that volunteers will waste their time on answering a question that has already been answered, and that is not respectful of the time of volunteers. I have downvoted, in the hope this will remind you in the future.

Comment: I am new to asking questions in forum, sorry for doing cross posting. Will never repeat this.